# How to read XML file with Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

I´m reading info from an XML file and it works in Android 2.3.6 but not in 4.2.2. Any idea about it?

This is my code in MainActivity

static final String URL = "http://static.infomaniak.ch/vod/playlist/87/298/298_playlist.xml";

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    TextView category[];
    //ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    //Log.d("xml",xml);
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
    doc.normalize();
    //NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("file");
    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("file");
    category = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
    String urls[] = new String[nodeList.getLength()];
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

        Node node = nodeList.item(i);
        category[i] = new TextView(this);
        Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
        NodeList websiteList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("file");
        Element websiteElement = (Element) websiteList.item(0);
        websiteList = websiteElement.getChildNodes();
        category[i].setText(websiteElement.getAttribute("url"));

        //layout.addView(category[i]);
        urls[i]=category[i].getText().toString();
        Log.d("urls[i]",category[i].getText().toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), category[i].getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

and this is XMLParser

public class XMLParser {

```
// constructor
public XMLParser() {

}

/**
 * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
 * @param url string
 * */
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}

/**
 * Getting XML DOM element
 * @param XML string
 * */
public Document getDomElement(String xml){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
}

/** Getting node value
  * @param elem element
  */
 public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
     Node child;
     if( elem != null){
         if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
             for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                 if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                     return child.getNodeValue();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return "";
 }

 /**
  * Getting node value
  * @param Element node
  * @param key string
  * */
 public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }
```

}

If you check the XML it has attributes and it´s the info I need, I can take it and use it in Android 2.3.6 but the app forces to close in 4.2.2
Maybe it happens to some one else and one something about this issue
Thanks in advance

---

Is it possible that the problem is because I´m using Action Bar Sherlock??

Comment: what is the error, post the logcat

Comment: It forces the close and I don´t know more

Comment: yes you do there is a log of what happened to make it crash in the logcat. Giving us code will not do much if we dont know the error and where it happened

Comment: How can I take the logcat if I install the app in a device?

Comment: do you not have the device hooked up to your computer?

Comment: yes, but Eclipse doesn´t recognize it to emulate directly on it

Comment: well figure out why the device is not getting recognized first because without an error there is no answer to this question. Also if you are installing the app from the computer to the device eclipse has obviously recognized its existance

Comment: I export the apk to install it

Comment: It only recognize some devices but I thought it was because of the Android version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with the Network call, I have to add:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

to solve it

Answer (score 0):

add this code where?

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new     StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```